# C# Create an instance of a class from a type FullName

Tags: c#, .net, createinstance

Does anybody know of an easy way to create an instance of a class given the FullName of a type (namespace.classname format), but not having the AssemblyQualifiedName? The FullName of the type is only contained in a single assembly that is referenced and available at runtime, so there is no ambiguity.

I don't have the type, I have a string - the fullname only, without the assembly part. I don't know the assembly, I just know it's referenced and there is only one assembly containing the type fullname.

Thanks!

EDIT:
This is to do with deserialization of instances from a proprietary protocol. I've recieved good answers, but what I'll end up do in order to have optimal solution and not iterate through all the assemblies is to create a static dictionary with fullName key and assembly qualified name as value, given I know which exactly are the classes and they are a limited set.

Comment: If you can get the `Assembly` object (perhaps via `typeof(SomeKnownType).Assembly`), you can use `thatAssembly.GetType(fullName)` ?

Comment: @ Marc Gravell no, I don't have the type, I have a string - the fullname only, without the assembly part. I don't know the assembly, I just know it's referenced and there is only one assembly containing the type fullname.

Comment: If your assembly is already referenced in your project, you don't need the Assembly Qualified Name.

Comment: in the comment above, I only used the `fullName`. The `SomeKnownType` was just **any other type** from that assembly, as a lazy mechanism of getting the `Assembly` instance

Comment: Have you take a look on [AssemblyResolve event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.appdomain.assemblyresolve?view=netframework-4.8) to resolve the missing assembly name?

Comment: @ Robert Harvey I don't know the assembly - might be few of the assemblies - I get only the fullName of the type from the protocol. So the only option is to iterate through the assemblies or define a static dictionary and use it at runtime to find the assembly. If you know a more convenient way, please post it as an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Load all of your assemblies and select over their types, then filter on the name.

```
public static object CreateType(string typeName)
{
    var allTypes = AppDomain.CurrentDomain
        .GetAssemblies()
        .SelectMany
        (
            a => a.GetTypes()
        );
    var type = allTypes.Single( t => t.Name == typeName );

    return Activator.CreateInstance(type);
}
```

You might consider adding some validation code to check for duplicates, and to ensure there is a default constructor.

Comment: Good - it's a way to do it and I mark it as an answer (provided the code), maybe slow if many assemblies and types, but that's it. I'd check for "&& t.IsClass && !t.IsInterface && !t.IsAbstract" to be sure CreateInstance will work - although in my particular case it will work without this check.

Answer (score 3):

You can [get all of the active assemblies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/851248/c-sharp-reflection-get-all-active-assemblies-in-a-solution) and then look through each one for a type with the full name you have.  You'll need to prepare for the possibility that there are multiple matches, or no matches, among the assemblies.

Comment: This is what I am trying to avoid doing. It's to do with several assemblies and types that are referenced for sure (proprietary) where these are being deserialized and recreated as instances. What I am thinking as an alternative is to create a static dictionary with fullName key and assembly qualified name as value.