# How can I get all the inherited classes of a base class?

Tags: c#, reflection, inheritance, assemblies

```
    class Foo { }

    class Foo1 : Foo { }

    class Foo2 : Foo { }
```

How would I be able to get all the classes that use Foo as a base class? The inherited classes aren't necessary in the same assembly.

Comment: at design or run time? If design then you can refer to this question for some tips http://stackoverflow.com/questions/282377/visual-studio-how-do-i-show-all-classes-inherited-from-a-base-class

Answer (score 29, accepted):

This is not fast, but as long as `Foo` is a concrete type (not an interface), then it should work. `Foo` itself is not returned by this code.

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()
                       .SelectMany(assembly => assembly.GetTypes())
                       .Where(type => type.IsSubclassOf(typeof(Foo)));
```

Comment: I don't think there's any faster way to do this.