# How to know Class <T>? Is there a way for Intellisense to autocomplete <T>?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, intellisense, generic-type-parameters

I have been using a 2d engine called NEZ. They use a List of class objects called "components" that are attached to an entity. `Component` is a public class that can be inherited.

Like let's say:

```cs
public class Ninja : Component
```

This is the Code:

```cs
/// <summary>
/// Adds a Component to the components list. Returns the Component.
/// </summary>
/// <returns>Scene.</returns>
/// <param name="component">Component.</param>
/// <typeparam name="T">The 1st type parameter.</typeparam>
public T AddComponent<T>(T component) where T : Component
{
    component.Entity = this;
    Components.Add(component);
    component.Initialize();
    return component;
}

/// <summary>
/// Adds a Component to the components list. Returns the Component.
/// </summary>
/// <returns>Scene.</returns>
/// <typeparam name="T">The 1st type parameter.</typeparam>
public T AddComponent<T>() where T : Component, new()
{
    var component = new T();
    component.Entity = this;
    Components.Add(component);
    component.Initialize();
    return component;
}
```

So the thing that is annoying is that Visual Studio doesn't give me a list of class objects that have the `Component` in them.

So, how would I know that  `_animator = Entity.AddComponent<SpriteAnimator>();` is a `Component`?

Besides that obvious answer that I would have to look at each .CS file and see if they inherit the `Component` class.

The question is: The object in `<T>` doesn't auto complete or doesn't even give me a possible items to fill the blank.

Is there a way for IntelliSense to search for each object that inherits the class `Component`?

If not, do you know if other IDE or intelli-tool (like Resharper) does the job?

I'm using Visual Studio 2019 with Roslynator Refactorings addon and also using Visual Assistance from Tomatoes Software.

Comment: Object Browser and look for descendants of Component? Also, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/282377/visual-studio-how-do-i-show-all-classes-inherited-from-a-base-class has some useful stuff

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1665120/how-can-i-get-all-the-inherited-classes-of-a-base-class and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5411694/get-all-inherited-classes-of-an-abstract-class/6944605 for code based ways.. I figure you'll only do it once/put the output in a text file..

Comment: No, there is no possibility to restrict intellisense to types allowed for a generic type parameter. The entry will scroll down a list of all types. You can send a [feature suggestion](https://learn.microsoft.com/visualstudio/ide/suggest-a-feature) to the .NET development team to *be able to filter on where clauses*. It's a good, intuitive and logic idea. Otherwise, indeed, you can take a llok on ReSharper or [TypeHierarchyViewer](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=munyabe.TypeHierarchyViewer).

Comment: that would be a nice improvement. Also like just searching for a class implementing an interface that would be great, like `IPoint a = new ` and then there is a proposal of differen IPoint implementations